# Why can't javascript manipulate an array over stored value?

Tags: javascript

I have basic javascript example like below

```js
const mainWidgets    = [{id:5}];
const sidebarWidgets = [{id:15}];
const direction      = "left";

let arrayToBeRemoved = direction==="left" ? mainWidgets : sidebarWidgets;

arrayToBeRemoved = arrayToBeRemoved.filter(e=>e.id!=5);

console.log( arrayToBeRemoved )
console.log( mainWidgets )
```

In this example I want to decide which array should be filtered according to direction variable.If its left,mainWidgets else sidebarWidgets array should be manipulated.

I expected to see when arrayToBeRemoved manipulated,mainWidgets also should be manipulated as its stored.But only arrayToBeRemoved variable manipulated not whats stored inside.Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `.filter()` creates a new array, doesn't change the existing one. And reassigning a variable doesn't change the object that was set to that variable. `a = {foo: 1}; b = a; a = {bar: 2}` still leaves you with `{foo: 1}` assigned to `b`.

Comment: Consider: `let a = 1; let b = a; b = 10` - would you expect `a` to change?

Comment: `arrayToBeRemoved` is a shallow copy of `mainWidgets` or `sidebarWidgets`, not a pointer to the original value as you may be expecting.

Comment: @oldgreg `arrayToBeRemoved` *is* a pointer right after the `let arrayToBeRemoved = ...` line. But `arrayToBeRemoved.filter()` creates a new copy of the array (i.e. it doesn't operate on the array for which `filter()` is called).

Comment: I think OP may be confused by the fact objects and arrays passed as argument of a function are passed by reference...

Comment: @georg While your comment is very valid, if you do a similar very simple comparison with the variable being an argument of a function call, there will be a different behaviour depending if the variable is an array or an number...

Comment: @LaurentS.: this is a common misconception. "Object" variables in javascript are no different from "primitive" ones.

Comment: @LaurentS. not too different. https://jsbin.com/celino/edit?js,console we're not in difference territory yet with reassignments.

Answer (score 0):

The filter() method in JS creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.